# To list Azure resource for all subscriptions in an azure account

Tags: azure, subscription

I need to list the Azure SQL servers in an Azure account for all subscriptions.
I need to list them for all subscriptions in one call or is there any other way to achieve this like using script for the Azure account other than API calls? Please help. It would be really helpful if the script is also provided.

I know this is possible, using Azure rest API, but we could list it only for one subscription at a time. But I am expecting to have the response for all subscriptions at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried using Azure CLI/Powershell?

Comment: You must have a read permissions for the other subscriptions.As I dont have authorization on other subscription,Iam able to see only the list of SQL Servers for my subscription only.You can try the below script.

Comment: `sub_ids=$(az account list --all --query '[].id' -o tsv)

for subscription_id in $sub_ids; 
do
    echo "List of SQL Servers for Subscription ID: $subscription_id"
    
    az resource list --subscription $subscription_id --resource-type Microsoft.DBforMySQL/servers --query '[].{Name: name, ResourceGroup: resourceGroup, Location: location}' --output table
done`
Run the script in bash

Comment: Output [Image](https://i.imgur.com/BPllsVM.png)

Comment: Use the [Azure Resource Graph Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/resource-graph/overview) and execute `resources | where type == "microsoft.sql/servers"`

Comment: The above which I gave is for MySQL.`sub_ids=$(az account list --all --query '[].id' -o tsv)
for subscription_id in $sub_ids; 
do
      echo "List of SQL Servers for Subscription ID: $subscription_id"      
  
    az sql server list --subscription $subscription_id --query '[].{Name: name, ResourceGroup: resourceGroup, Location: location}' --output table    
done` ,This is for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Peter Bons for the comment.

Yes, you can check the results in Resource Graph Explorer.

If you want to go with CloudShell, check the below Bash script to get the list of SQL resources.

Open the `Azure Cloud Shell`,
[image]

- You need to have read permissions on other subscriptions to list the resources.
- In Bash, run the below command to get the list of SQL query

```cs
 az sql server list
```

- First get all the subscriptions into a variable

```cs
sub_ids=$(az account list --all --query '[].id' -o tsv)
```

- Loop the Subscription ID to get the list of SQL Servers.

```cs
sub_ids=$(az account list --all --query '[].id' -o tsv)
for sub_id in $sub_ids; 
do
echo "List of SQL Servers for Subscription ID: $sub_id"     
  
az sql server list --subscription $sub_id --query '[].{SQLServer: name, ResourceGroup: resourceGroup, Location: location}' --output table
    
done
```

***Output:*** [image]

As I don't have authorization on other subscription, Iam getting the below error.

[image]

Make sure you have required permissions to read other subscriptions.

Comment: Thanks @Harshitha for the answers, I hope this should help, but my ultimate requirement is to have the response with the failover group and secondary type details for the SQL databases created in the account for all subscriptions, In rest api, we can achieve this by [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/databases/list-by-server?view=rest-sql-2021-11-01&tabs=HTTP] url, but can I get the similar response with the details I mentioned, with the steps you have given and the right script?

Comment: Need to check it..will let you know If I can retrieve those details.

Comment: Need to add the property names in the query list.

Comment: @SwethaBalakrishnan - Can you list out the property names which you want to retrieve.

Comment: Can you please post a new question with all the requirements which you have asked in the comments in detail.

Comment: @Harshitha, Please find the new question link here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77798269/to-get-azure-sql-resource-details-for-all-subscriptions-in-an-azure-account